# AOP solution for domain/range annotation-parsing of function definitions and invocations

Tags: java

In the form of non-existent Java annotations, here is what I would like:

```
class Example {
    static double sqrt(@Domain(0, Double.MAX_VALUE) x) {
        return Math.sqrt(x);
    }

    @Range(0, Double.MAX_VALUE)
    static double square(double x) {
        return x * x;
    }

    @Range(-Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE)
    static double add(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        sqrt(square(42));   // fine
        sqrt(add(40, 2));   // not fine because `add` may return a negative number
    }
}
```

I want an annotation parser that will do the following:

1. Allows me to specify a `Domain` on parameters that are numbers (i.e. `@Domain(-1, 1) double x`
2. Allows me to specify a `Range` on functions that return numbers (i.e.`@Range(-1, 1) double foo() { ... }`.
3. Throw an error if, somewhere in the source code, a function that has domain-restricted parameters is called with range-restricted parameters whose range(s) lie outside of the domain(s).
4. It should assume all functions that aren't annotated with a `@Range` will lie outside the domain of any function they're used in.

Comment: Did you have a look at the obvious [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/)?

Comment: As I read it again, this is probably not an AOP kind of thing and more something for [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have looked at AspectJ and FindBugs a little. However, I'm more interested in a specific solution than a framework I could use to write my own solution. This is only because I'm lazy, and I don't want to learn the frameworks if it isn't necessary.